# PritUnl VPN : Unable to communicate with helper service, try restarting, windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, pritunl

Similar question for mac [Pritunl error on macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141514/pritunl-client-unable-to-communicate-with-helper-service-try-restarting)

When trying to open Pritunl VPN tool on Windows 10, I see an error: `Pritunl - Service Error [Content] Unable to communicate with helper service, try restarting computer.`

Solutions tried:

- Killing all Pritunl programs from task manager
- Restarting computer
- Uninstalling Pritunl, restarting pc, installing again (worked once in this case but showed an error on next start)
- Restarting windows services

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps to solve:

1. Press Windows + R.
2. Type `services.msc` and press `OK`.
3. Find service whose name is "Pritunl Helper Service".
4. Right click and click `start`.
5. Right click and click `Properties`.
6. Change `Startup type` to `Automatic`.
7. Go to `Recovery` tab. Set `On first failure` action to `Restart service`.
8. Click `OK`.

Enjoy Pritunl.

Comment: I did this on Windows 10. The service is already running but I restarted it nonetheless and changed all those options. Still getting the same error. Can anybody help?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Restarted service, stopped all pritunl instances, reinstalled pritunl. Still getting "Unable to communicate with helper service, try restarting" (windows)

Comment: @fantastory, please let me know how you fixed it. I have hard time trying to fix the same issue.

Comment: Tried this. In my case it was already set to Automatic startup. Then I clicked Start button, and it started running but gave the error "windows could not start pritunl helper service on local computer"

Answer (score 4):

Re-installing Pritunl client (https://client.pritunl.com/#install) helped in my case.

Comment: It doesn't help me to fix this. Is there any other solution? Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem on MacOS and this solution simply worked for me.